# Why isn't PHP/Laravel incrementing this value?

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, reference, phpunit

Unit testing with Laravel 5 and sqlite.  I have a simple test where a `User` creates a `Post`.

```
/** @test */
public function it_should_increment_post_count_when_a_user_makes_a_post()
{
    // Given
    $u = User::first();
    $count1 = $u->posts->count();
    var_dump($count1);

    // When
    $p = new Post();
    $p->title = 'My Title';
    $p->content = 'This is the content';
    $p->user_id = $u->id;
    $p->save(); // This is definitely saving
    $count2 = $u->posts->count();
    var_dump($count2);

    // Then
    $this->assertEquals($count1+1, $count2);
}
```

The results are as follows:

```
root@7053bd7f558c:/var/www/laravel# phpunit
PHPUnit 5.5.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.....Fint(11)
int(11)
.                                                             7 / 7 (100%)

Time: 1.98 seconds, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) BasicUserTest::it_should_increment_post_count_when_a_user_makes_a_post
Failed asserting that 11 matches expected 12.

/var/www/laravel/tests/BasicUserTest.php:96

FAILURES!
Tests: 7, Assertions: 11, Failures: 1.
```

It is certainly saving to the database (if I run this without `use DatabaseTransactions;` it increments every time).  Is `$count1` a reference to `$u->posts->count()` somehow?

EDIT:
A similar variation yields a strange property:

```
/** @test */
public function it_should_increment_post_count_when_a_user_makes_a_post()
{
    // Given
    $p = new Post([
        'title' => 'tha title',
        'content' => 'tha content',
    ]);
    $u_old = User::first();
    var_dump($u_old->posts->count());

    // When
    $u_old->posts()->save($p);

    // Then
    $u_new = User::first();
    $this->assertEquals($u_old->posts->count()+1, $u_new->posts->count());
}
```

This works, but if I comment out the line `var_dump($u_old->posts->count());`, it fails.

Comment: Try putting parenthesis around `$count1+1` ie `($count1+1)`. Also, what is this test gaining you? Isn't this a built in Laravel ability?

Comment: @nerdlyist  No change, see new edit.  Just getting used to Laravel, this isn't a serious test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write this:

```
$u->posts->count();
```

It is not the `count()` that is cached in the model. It is the `posts` relationship. You are fetching **all of that user's posts** as a `Collection` (which is basically a glorified array), and then `count`ing the number of items in the collection.

If you only need the number of posts, you should **not** load the full collection. You should only load the collection when you actually need details about each post.

Instead, do this:

```
$u->posts()->count();
```

Notice the `()` after posts. That means you are actually building a query to select to the total number of posts. This:

1. requires less memory (Eloquent objects are huge)
2. will be easier on your database (selecting count instead of * from table)
3. will be pulled fresh from the DB and accurate each time it is called

Comment: Great points. This will be less expensive than my approach, indeed! +1 and should really get marked as correct answer.

Comment: @camelCase thanks. `fresh` certainly has its uses but I think for just updating a counter there are better options

Answer (score 2):

`count` keep the same value because the value is stored on the Eloquent model.
This is a value kept in memory.

So, after insert, you need to make a new request.
For example:
`<?php DB::table('name')->count(); ?>`

Or may by just a real count: `<?php $count2 = count($y->posts); ?>`

(I don't remember if there is a tips to reload the counter value ...)

Comment: `$count2 = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id', 1)->count();` works, but `$count2 = count($u->posts);` fails.  I would like a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: The only solution I can found is to reload the object (as you already did it).
I don't remember ... but I just read something about `withCount`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13414 Maybe someting (reload it) ?

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is correct, but thought I'd give input for another option. It saves a second query after the insert.

After inserting, you can refresh the relationship data on your `User` model.

```
// Get fresh data for posts relationship
$u = $u->fresh();
```

From the [API docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fresh):

> Reload a fresh model instance from the database.

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to be working:  `$p->save(); $u->fresh(['posts']); $count2 = $u->posts->count();`  It's a shame because this is exactly the sort of answer I am looking for.

Comment: @MarkKaravan Hmm it _should_ be working...try dropping the argument maybe? I believe without it, the entire model is refreshed. And `posts` is defined as a `hasMany` relationship in your `User` model?

Comment: Got it, you have to use `$u = $u->fresh();`.  Wish the docs were more clear about that.  If you edit your post I'll mark as correct.

Comment: Interesting, I swear I've used without assigning to new variable but perhaps I'm just forgetting. Heck, I could barely remember it was called `fresh` :)

Comment: Yes, this works, but you are still needlessly querying all of that user's posts from the DB. Even worse, you are now doing it **twice**! You shouldn't do that. See my answer

Comment: Thanks @andrewtweber, I've marked yours as correct.